# Chrome Webdriver detach option in Java

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using ChromeDriver for Selenium in Java.

I want to leave the browser open after the test is complete. The default behavior is to close the browser. 
I have tried the following

```
 options.setCapability("detach", true);
 driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

or

```
options.setExperimentalOption("detach", true);
```

Neither seems to work. What is the correct way to use this in Java?

Answer (score 1):

According to `detach` the property description

> If false, Chrome will be quit when ChromeDriver is killed, regardless of whether the session is quit. If true, Chrome will only be quit if the session is quit (or closed). Note, if true, and the session is not quit, ChromeDriver cannot clean up the temporary user data directory that the running Chrome instance is using.

which means (AFAIU) that this only controls if you want to keep your browser open or not in case when your WebDriver process is unexpectedly terminated. This does not cover your particular case.

You can just leave your driver active after the test has completed (not `quit` it) and create new WebDriver object for each new test. However this is not effective approach from performance standpoint.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to keep the browser open after quitting the ChromeDriver. Otherwise a lot of chrome driver tasks keep running in the background.

Comment: Why do you need to have browsers open? Having them open would consume a lot of resources even without running webdrivers.